# Функция потери loss возвращает nan

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tensorflow, keras

Сразу повторюсь я начинающий по нейросетям. У меня есть задача класификации двух классов.
Когда я запускаю обучение `model.fit(X, Y, epochs=50)`, мне выводит функция потери `loss` ровно `nan`. В качестве функции потери я поставил `binary_crossentropy`, а в качестве оптимизатора `adam`. Если что модель нейросети

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    Dense(units=16, input_dim=6, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Крч проблема была в том что где-то в датасете было значение `nan`